# ASP.NET MVC JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I'm trying to get JQuery to work with my project but it does not want to fire off. Under the Scripts folder contains jQuery-3.3.1.js ,jQuery-3.3.1.min.js , and jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js.

The _LayoutFile.cshtml View, I moved the Scripts.Render bundle to the head portion.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</head>
```

I have a Controller that delivers a Model to View and the view looks like this.

```
 <head>
   @section Scripts
   {
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".fancy_title").lettering();
   });
   alert("Hello");
   </script>
   }
```

No matter what i try i cannot get the events to fire. Ran through a couple tutorials and i cannot get the Jquery to work. If someone can point me in the correct direction that would be awesome.

Comment: You have JQuery included twice. Jquery-3.3.1.min.js is the minified version of Jquery-3.3.1.js. They contain the same code. Remove one of them.

Comment: It looks like you're also rendering a bundle. You may be including it one or more times again in the bundle. Check your bundle configuration and see.

Comment: Include only one instance of jQuery. Currently you are including more than one.

Comment: Delete both the `~/Scripts/jquery-` and move the `~/Scripts/jquery.lettering` after your bundles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to just remove all redundant jQuery script tags which causing the problem because you're loading multiple jQuery instances:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Then add `jquery.lettering` script to existing `~/bundles/jquery` in proper order (i.e. the jQuery must be on the top-most, see [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)) like this example:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js",
                 "~/Scripts/jquery-lettering-0.6.1.js"));

    // other stuff
}
```

And you can simply use `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` to render all necessary scripts into layout/view page.